# How to get Date of previous Monday and Previous sunday in Datastudio with calculated fields?

Tags: looker-studio

In datastudio I can use Calculated fields to show any data.
However for this I want to show Date of previous monday and previous sunday in Datastudio with calculated fields since my report shows data within that days.

I tried something like but didn't work for Google datastudio, it works with mysql

```
subdate(curdate(), WEEKDAY(curdate()) + 7); # Monday
subdate(curdate(), WEEKDAY(curdate()) + 1); # Sunday
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be achieved by using either of the following sets of [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685):

- ***Current Week***: #1 and #2
- ***Week Minus 1***: #3 and #4

### 1) Sunday: Current Week

```
DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK)
```

### 2) Monday: Current Week

```
DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), ISOWEEK)
```

### 3) Sunday: Week -1

```
DATETIME_SUB(DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

### 4) Monday: Week -1

```
DATETIME_SUB(DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), ISOWEEK), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/5df97f23-25f4-47e0-afca-5595401e670b) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]